# Upload a file into Google Drive and record Form answers in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to have form data upload into a spreadsheet and at the same time upload a file into my google drive. The file upload is working. But as I'm not a programmer at all, I'm having difficulties putting the info into a spreadsheet. I just don't know if the spreadsheet has to exist or not and how to access it. Can someone please help? 
My current code is below but gives an error message.

I'm not sure what the submissionSSkey should be, is it the name of the spreadsheet? I'm sorry for not knowing such a trivial thing. But I'm really stuck here. And should I do anything else with the spreadsheet? Fill out the first row for instance?

```
// start form
var submissionSSKey = "Uploading";

function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}
var url;


function processForm(form) {
try {

  // Record submission in spreadsheet
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues([[LastName,FirstName,EmailAddress,AbstractTitlel]]);
var dropbox = "Abstracts XXI";
var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

var blob = form.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
file.setName( form.select + "_"  + form.LastName + new Date );
file.setDescription( form.AbstractTitle);
url=file.getUrl();    
return "\<br/> File uploaded successfully. \<br/> \<br/> Thank you for the submission of your abstract for SBDD XXI 2016. \<br/> \<br/> To view the uploaded abstracht please copy the URL below into your browser \<br/>" +  file.getUrl();

} catch (error) {

return error.toString();
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this bit of code before the return statement. Replace the ID and SHEET NAME with the actual values. Also, you may have to republish the web app.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREASHEET_ID");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
sheet.appendRow([form.select, form,LastName, url]);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Where can I find the ID? Is it in the spreadsheet properties? :)

Comment: Open the sheet in a new tab, you'll find the ID in the URL.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This works now. The next error is that it can't read the setvalues([[LastName,...]]) although these are defined in the accompanying form, e.g.
<h2>Corresponding author</h2>
    <label> Last name </label>
    <input type="text" id="Name1" name="LastName"  style= "width: 200px" > 
    <label> First name </label>
    <input type="text" id="Name2" name="FirstName" style = "width: 200px"> Am I supposed to redefine them in the .gs file? Or how can I address them?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just the let you know that all issues are resolved. Have a nice day!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.